# forecast.HoltWinters lower limit?

Tags: r, forecasting

I plotted from a data frame by using `forecast.HoltWinters` function. However, in graph lower limit is minus. How Can I arrange the lower limit as zero? The code below did not work. Thank you.

```
library(forecast)
casesseriesforecasts2 <- forecast.HoltWinters(casesseriesforecasts, h=8,lower=0)
plot.forecast(casesseriesforecasts2)
```

data

```
structure(list(method = "HoltWinters", model = structure(list(
fitted = structure(c(16352, 1558.78360573168, 240.89056661416, 
123.482559033918, 113.022954320328, 112.091132607147, 112.008118790762, 
112.000723284075, 112.000064435686, 112.000005740425, 19.0869418774497, 
103.722593026472, 30.1913869583035, 128.395582887599, 113.460644121194, 
26.5043654499464, 104.383393939123, 3228.46348032057, 326.785488915318, 
131.134736706388, 14.4152239157357, 108.771874640265, 111.712413864057, 
166.629119996883, 3835.21095053019, 443.692152949984, 47.7257069229214, 
6.07359625225211, 148.108881487504, 115.216855773241, 112.286582154848, 
114.758267952348, 112.245727638773, 112.021891300447, 118.378336621581, 
112.568231087188, 112.050622378153, 166.659250202149, 116.86946472254, 
33.1844356790589, 104.978505767486, 111.374471505952, 19.9421268355168, 
5.4202467823966, 416.769816278597, 88.1401388937625, 109.874380795349, 
144.603477781794, 419.149288967374, 64.6683997204517, 107.783338465671, 
111.624347488991, 111.966533996651, 111.997018592057, 111.999734393342, 
111.999976337724, 111.999997891983, 541.039711739565, 150.222144159646, 
177.347160489922, 191.605525148625, 119.091869994501, 80.749866221837, 
109.215998692908, 26.1262199192945, 15.9912089022784, 103.446801418331, 
111.238015548982, 16352, 1558.78360573168, 240.89056661416, 
123.482559033918, 113.022954320328, 112.091132607147, 112.008118790762, 
112.000723284075, 112.000064435686, 112.000005740425, 19.0869418774497, 
103.722593026472, 30.1913869583035, 128.395582887599, 113.460644121194, 
26.5043654499464, 104.383393939123, 3228.46348032057, 326.785488915318, 
131.134736706388, 14.4152239157357, 108.771874640265, 111.712413864057, 
166.629119996883, 3835.21095053019, 443.692152949984, 47.7257069229214, 
6.07359625225211, 148.108881487504, 115.216855773241, 112.286582154848, 
114.758267952348, 112.245727638773, 112.021891300447, 118.378336621581, 
112.568231087188, 112.050622378153, 166.659250202149, 116.86946472254, 
33.1844356790589, 104.978505767486, 111.374471505952, 19.9421268355168, 
5.4202467823966, 416.769816278597, 88.1401388937625, 109.874380795349, 
144.603477781794, 419.149288967374, 64.6683997204517, 107.783338465671, 
111.624347488991, 111.966533996651, 111.997018592057, 111.999734393342, 
111.999976337724, 111.999997891983, 541.039711739565, 150.222144159646, 
177.347160489922, 191.605525148625, 119.091869994501, 80.749866221837, 
109.215998692908, 26.1262199192945, 15.9912089022784, 103.446801418331, 
111.238015548982), .Dim = c(68L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("xhat", "level")), .Tsp = c(2008.08333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix")), x = structure(c(16352L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 10L, 
112L, 23L, 138L, 112L, 18L, 112L, 3534L, 43L, 112L, 3L, 118L, 
112L, 172L, 4194L, 112L, 9L, 2L, 162L, 112L, 112L, 115L, 
112L, 112L, 119L, 112L, 112L, 172L, 112L, 25L, 112L, 112L, 
11L, 4L, 457L, 56L, 112L, 148L, 446L, 30L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 583L, 112L, 180L, 193L, 112L, 77L, 
112L, 18L, 15L, 112L, 112L, 1L), .Tsp = c(2008, 2013.66666666667, 
12), class = "ts"), alpha = 0.910912339548542, beta = FALSE, 
gamma = FALSE, coefficients = structure(10.8208468980703, .Names = "a"), 
seasonal = "additive", SSE = 319244834.790406, call = HoltWinters(x = casestimeseries, 
    beta = FALSE, gamma = FALSE)), .Names = c("fitted", "x",
```

"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "coefficients", "seasonal", "SSE", 
"call"), class = "HoltWinters"), level = c(80, 95), mean = structure(c(10.8208468980703, 
10.8208468980703, 10.8208468980703, 10.8208468980703, 10.8208468980703, 
10.8208468980703, 10.8208468980703, 10.8208468980703), .Tsp = c(2013.75, 
2014.33333333333, 12), class = "ts"), lower = structure(c(-2765.80536739846, 
-3745.08448556263, -4517.31305117681, -5175.81277534505, -5759.65054319398, 
-6289.61658207136, -6778.33841834582, -7234.16743889888, -4235.66249787343, 
-5733.34066706851, -6914.36234198927, -7921.45076347691, -8814.35357641357, 
-9624.86668970184, -10372.3022383832, -11069.4325665042), .Dim = c(8L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("80%", "95%"))), upper = structure(c(2787.4470611946, 
3766.72617935877, 4538.95474497295, 5197.45446914119, 5781.29223699012, 
6311.2582758675, 6799.98011214196, 7255.80913269502, 4257.30419166957, 
5754.98236086465, 6936.00403578541, 7943.09245727305, 8835.99527020971, 
9646.50838349799, 10393.9439321793, 11091.0742603004), .Dim = c(8L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("80%", "95%"))), x = structure(c(16352L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 10L, 112L, 
23L, 138L, 112L, 18L, 112L, 3534L, 43L, 112L, 3L, 118L, 112L, 
172L, 4194L, 112L, 9L, 2L, 162L, 112L, 112L, 115L, 112L, 112L, 
119L, 112L, 112L, 172L, 112L, 25L, 112L, 112L, 11L, 4L, 457L, 
56L, 112L, 148L, 446L, 30L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 583L, 112L, 180L, 193L, 112L, 77L, 112L, 18L, 15L, 112L, 
112L, 1L), .Tsp = c(2008, 2013.66666666667, 12), class = "ts"), 
    xname = "x", fitted = structure(c(16352, 1558.78360573168, 
    240.89056661416, 123.482559033918, 113.022954320328, 112.091132607147, 
    112.008118790762, 112.000723284075, 112.000064435686, 112.000005740425, 
    19.0869418774497, 103.722593026472, 30.1913869583035, 128.395582887599, 
    113.460644121194, 26.5043654499464, 104.383393939123, 3228.46348032057, 
    326.785488915318, 131.134736706388, 14.4152239157357, 108.771874640265, 
    111.712413864057, 166.629119996883, 3835.21095053019, 443.692152949984, 
    47.7257069229214, 6.07359625225211, 148.108881487504, 115.216855773241, 
    112.286582154848, 114.758267952348, 112.245727638773, 112.021891300447, 
    118.378336621581, 112.568231087188, 112.050622378153, 166.659250202149, 
    116.86946472254, 33.1844356790589, 104.978505767486, 111.374471505952, 
    19.9421268355168, 5.4202467823966, 416.769816278597, 88.1401388937625, 
    109.874380795349, 144.603477781794, 419.149288967374, 64.6683997204517, 
    107.783338465671, 111.624347488991, 111.966533996651, 111.997018592057, 
    111.999734393342, 111.999976337724, 111.999997891983, 541.039711739565, 
    150.222144159646, 177.347160489922, 191.605525148625, 119.091869994501, 
    80.749866221837, 109.215998692908, 26.1262199192945, 15.9912089022784, 
    103.446801418331, 111.238015548982), .Tsp = c(2008.08333333333, 
    2013.66666666667, 12), class = "ts"), residuals = structure(c(-16240, 
    -1446.78360573168, -128.89056661416, -11.4825590339183, -1.02295432032754, 
    -0.0911326071466902, -0.00811879076154298, -0.000723284074638286, 
    -6.44356860561857e-05, -102.000005740425, 92.9130581225503, 
    -80.7225930264717, 107.808613041696, -16.3955828875987, -95.4606441211941, 
    85.4956345500536, 3429.61660606088, -3185.46348032057, -214.785488915318, 
    -128.134736706388, 103.584776084264, 3.22812535973524, 60.2875861359428, 
    4027.37088000312, -3723.21095053019, -434.692152949984, -45.7257069229214, 
    155.926403747748, -36.1088814875037, -3.21685577324067, 2.71341784515222, 
    -2.75826795234815, -0.245727638772934, 6.97810869955346, 
    -6.37833662158081, -0.568231087188494, 59.9493776218466, 
    -54.6592502021487, -91.8694647225403, 78.8155643209411, 7.02149423251404, 
    -100.374471505952, -15.9421268355168, 451.579753217603, -360.769816278597, 
    23.8598611062375, 38.1256192046514, 301.396522218206, -389.149288967374, 
    47.3316002795483, 4.21666153432852, 0.37565251100898, 0.0334660033485079, 
    0.00298140794298263, 0.000265606658487627, 2.36622758080784e-05, 
    471.000002108017, -429.039711739565, 29.7778558403542, 15.6528395100779, 
    -79.605525148625, -42.0918699945007, 31.250133778163, -91.2159986929084, 
    -11.1262199192945, 96.0087910977216, 8.55319858166878, -110.238015548982
    ), .Tsp = c(2008.08333333333, 2013.66666666667, 12), class = "ts")), .Names = c("method", 
"model", "level", "mean", "lower", "upper", "x", "xname", "fitted", 
"residuals"), class = "forecast")

Comment: You'll need to give us a fully reproducible example before we can help you.

Comment: I edited my post to add reproducible data. But seems something wrong. Can you check please?